# Google Sheets Query + Import range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

need some help

=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1ygkNl_q1V01x8e-XTLS-gdyTC1lsWviJPJ_sb28qz-s","'QA REJECT'!C3:K"),"select Col3,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col10,Col11,Col12 where Col7 = 'HP BOX (443X270X285)'")

**Output:** Error
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col10

Comment: Share a copy of your sample workbook.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this** 
> you selected Col10,Col11,Col12 and you have only 9 columns in the query from `C` to `K`.

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1ygkNl_q1V01x8e-XTLS-gdyTC1lsWviJPJ_sb28qz-s","'QA REJECT'!C1:K"),"select * where Col5 = 'HP BOX (443X270X285)'")
```

[image]